# MongoDB query works from shell, but fails with the NodeJS driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection called "files" with these documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "8e1e0d87-fa8f-4c0a-bd7f-78f1b84aefbb",
    "groupId" : "7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b",
    "uploadDate" : NumberLong(1427392635983),
    "file" : "n/ws/hs/f25a2613-3094-4150-9268-c6248475218d",
    "length" : 56353,
    "contentType" : "image/other"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "de392172-27a5-45bb-ba11-d1c494847dda",
    "groupId" : "7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b",
    "uploadDate" : NumberLong(1427392687008),
    "file" : "y/ba/co/22c987c2-2ab3-46a3-8ff8-474a070f2fcc",
    "length" : 56353,
    "contentType" : "image/other"
}
```

I wanted to get the sum of the value of the length field for all the documents with the `groupId` `7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b` with the `NodeJS` driver.

I've tried this query in Mongo Shell:

```
  db.files.aggregate(
        [
        {$match:{"groupId":"7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b"}},
        { $group: { "_id": "test", "totalLength":{$sum:"$length"} } }
        ]
    )
```

And it worked. I'm trying to do the same in a NodeJS method:

```
 function(db, callback) {
    var groupId = "7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b";
      console.log("*****sending query");
        db.collection('files').aggregate(
            [   
               {$match:{"groupId":groupId}},
               { $group: { "_id": "test", "totalLength":{$sum:"$length"} } }
            ]).toArray(function(err, result) {
                console.log("***received");
                console.log(result);
                callback(result);
             }
           );
    }
```

This doesn't work. It stops abruptly after printing ******sending query, with no further error information or anything of that sort.
I'm not sure what's going wrong here; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `toArray` call and use the regular callback for `aggregate` and log the error and result arguments for that

Comment: I did that, and I guess it worked:
 `db.collection("mediaFiles").aggregate(
        [
            {$match:{"tenantId":"7ee973c0-54b5-11e4-aaed-0002a5d5c51b"}},
            { $group: { "_id": "baea015d-50d5-4268-b007-2f7ae67ad9c8", "totalLength":{$sum:"$length"} } }
        ],
        function(err, done) {
            console.log("***received");
            console.log(err);
            console.log(done);

        }
    )`


It printed `[ { _id: 'baea015d-50d5-4268-b007-2f7ae67ad9c8',
    totalLength: 112666 } ]`

I see it is an array. But what could be the reason why the toArray method fails?

Comment: Don't know, did you try logging the `err` argument in the `toArray` call ?

Comment: Yes, `toArray(function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
        });`

Nothing gets printed whatsoever.

Comment: This probably is a `bug` within the NodeJS Driver.